# Having trouble getting Elastic Search Aggregates to work

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

**Problem:**

I only want 1 item from each variant group to be returned.

Context: 
I am using Elasticsearch 7.
If I search Bell peppers, there should only be one item listed. Technically I sell 4 conventional and 4 organic bell peppers. On the Bell Pepper details page, it allows you to select the color, so there's no reason to flood search results page with tons of bell peppers. I am pretty sure Aggregates are the solution, but all of the examples I have found, and suggestions for how to do this seem to be failing for me.

**Does anyone see my error, or have a suggestion for an elegant way to achieve this?**

**Document structure:**

```
{
  'id': 2843,
  'name': 'Yellow Bell pepper',
  'variant_id': 3311
}
```

**Query used:**

```
{
  'query': {
    'query_string': {
      'query': 'bell pepper',
      'fields': [ 'name' ]
    }
  },
  'aggs': {
    'variants' : {
      'terms' : { 'field' : 'variant_id' } 
    }
  }
};
```

**Current response:**

```
  "total": 23,
  "statusCode": 200,
  "hits": [
    {
      "id": 2843,
      "name": "Yellow Bell pepper",
      "variant_id": 3311
    },
    {
      "id": 2842,
      "name": "Orange Bell Pepper",
      "variant_id": 3311
    },
    {
      "id": 2839,
      "name": "Organic Green Bell Pepper",
      "variant_id": 3312
    },
    {
      "id": 2840,
      "name": "Organic Yellow Bell Pepper",
      "variant_id": 3312
    },
  ]
}
```

**The response I need:**

```
  "total": 23,
  "statusCode": 200,
  "hits": [
    {
      "id": 2843,
      "name": "Yellow Bell pepper",
      "variant_id": 3311
    },
    {
      "id": 2839,
      "name": "Organic Green Bell Pepper",
      "variant_id": 3312
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GET stackoverflow/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "bell pepper",
      "fields": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "variants": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "variant_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "results": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.22380026,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "stackoverflow",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Wt7GrnEBo-Xqbvtw2rIB",
        "_score" : 0.22380026,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2843,
          "name" : "Yellow Bell pepper",
          "variant_id" : 3311
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "stackoverflow",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "W97GrnEBo-Xqbvtw9rKy",
        "_score" : 0.22380026,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2842,
          "name" : "Orange Bell Pepper",
          "variant_id" : 3311
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "stackoverflow",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "XN7HrnEBo-XqbvtwDbJ2",
        "_score" : 0.19908613,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2839,
          "name" : "Organic Green Bell Pepper",
          "variant_id" : 3312
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "stackoverflow",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Xd7HrnEBo-XqbvtwMrLw",
        "_score" : 0.19908613,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2840,
          "name" : "Organic Yellow Bell Pepper",
          "variant_id" : 3312
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "variants" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 3311,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "results" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 0.22380026,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "stackoverflow",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "Wt7GrnEBo-Xqbvtw2rIB",
                  "_score" : 0.22380026,
                  "_source" : {
                    "id" : 2843,
                    "name" : "Yellow Bell pepper",
                    "variant_id" : 3311
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 3312,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "results" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 0.19908613,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "stackoverflow",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "XN7HrnEBo-XqbvtwDbJ2",
                  "_score" : 0.19908613,
                  "_source" : {
                    "id" : 2839,
                    "name" : "Organic Green Bell Pepper",
                    "variant_id" : 3312
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This uses filter_path in order to omit the noise and sets size to 0 in order to not return any hits since you will not be using them.

```
GET stackoverflow/_search?filter_path=aggregations.variants.buckets.results.hits.hits._source
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "bell pepper",
      "fields": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "variants": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "variant_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "results": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "variants" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "results" : {
            "hits" : {
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_source" : {
                    "id" : 2843,
                    "name" : "Yellow Bell pepper",
                    "variant_id" : 3311
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "results" : {
            "hits" : {
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_source" : {
                    "id" : 2839,
                    "name" : "Organic Green Bell Pepper",
                    "variant_id" : 3312
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't think I would have found this solution on my own.

Comment: Glad I could help